# Is High blood cholesterol a cause of heart disease even if the ratio of HDL:LDL is high?

Tags: cholesterol

In my limited understanding,

LDL blood Cholesterol -> Clogs Arteries

HDL blood Cholesterol -> carries LDL cholesterol away from Arteries

Then based on this, does total cholesterol even matter? As long as the ratio of HDL : LDL is high, then the HDL cholesterol should save them from getting their arteries clogged by the LDL.

Comment: If you agree I'll migrate this over to medical Sciences. +1 for the question.

Comment: Hi Hisham, welcome to Medical Sciences. I recognize your question was migrated here, but questions on Medical Sciences are required to show results of prior research. As described in the help center and [this meta post](//medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.